Replicating IPv4 LAN configuration with IPv6
My setup consists of a cable modem (provided by my ISP), an ASUS router and several LAN clients. Some of these clients have static IPv4 addresses assigned by the router's DHCP server.
Now I activated IPv6 on the ASUS, choosing the 'Passthrough' option as instructed. The clients are assigned addresses according to prefix delegated by the cable modem (in my case 2a02:908:532:bca0::/64).
How can I replicate the IPv4 configuration (with static IP addresses for my Synology NAS and Linux server) in this context? The 'Passthrough' setup on the ASUS router does not allow any further configuration, and I am unsure how to switch to the 'Native' setup with the following parameters displayed in the cable modem interface (and if I would be able to configure DHCPv6 with static IPv6 addresses on the router afterwards):

AFTR address
IPv6 address (/62)
IPv6 prefix delegation (/64)
Primary and secondary DNS IPv6


Do you really need static IPv6 addresses though? Especially seeing how the prefix is probably still dynamic. IPv4 is still perfectly fine, especially for SOHO networks.

No, I do not need IPv6 in my LAN, but I was wondering whether I could make the switch even though my ISP does not provide static IPv6.

SuperUser's format works best if you keep each Question post limited to a single question. Please edit your post to focus on a single question.
